# How to sort dates in a List

Tags: java, sorting, date

How can i sort the dates inside the list?

I have read that this can be achieved by using TreeMap, as it is a sorted and navigable map that organizes elements in a self-balancing binary tree. but its also expensive.

My question is - What is the BEST and EFFICIENT way to achieve the result?

Comment: You have to define what your requirements are before you can pick the BEST algorithm. Do you need fast execution time? Do you need low memory overhead? Do you need fast retrieval or insertion of an element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends. If you want to have "always sorted" container then [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is your friend. Adding another element to the TreeMap will be O(log(n)) - (very good, faster than linear).

If you need to sort it only once (no adding elements later), then just put it to [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and use [sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method. It will be optimal - O(n log(n))

**Update:**

As JB Nizet mentioned in the comment, Set (TreeSet) cannot contain duplicates. List (ArrayList) can. 
If performance is important and there is a lot of elements and you need to store sorted elements allowing duplicates, then you can store it in TreeSet, but need to implement counting (`add()` will  `element.count++`, and `remove()` will `element.count--` for example).

Comment: A TreeMap is a Map. It's not a collection. At least recommend TreeSet instead. But a List and a Set don't have the same behavior. One accepts duplicates and the other doesn't. This should be the primary choice factor.

Comment: @JBNizet: Totally agree. I meant TreeSet (which is implemented on top of TreeMap). Fixed in my post. Thank you.